# How can I handle a folder-like model structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this Rails model: (Parameters removed for clarity)

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => :folder 
  has_many :children, :class_name => :folder
end
```

I want this model to be used like a file system folder. How do I have to configure the routes and the controller to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As for the model: check out [`acts_as_tree`](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree)

2) As for the routes: do something like

```
map.folder '/folders/*path', :controller => 'folders', :action => 'show'
```

and in the `FoldersController`,

```
def show
  # params[:path] contains an array of folder names
  @folder = Folder.root
  params[:path].each |name|
    @folder = @folder.children.find_by_name(name) or raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
  # there you go, @folder contains the folder identified by the path
end
```